# Power external hard drive though USB -- safe to use USB charger?

Tags: usb, power, usb-power, hard-drive, safety

I would like to connect an external hard drive to the Raspberry Pi.  This hard drive must be powered through USB and comes with a cable that has two ends (to ensure sufficient power).  The cable is similar (not identical) to this one:

[image]

If I plug both ends into the Raspberry Pi, the hard drive shows symptoms of not getting sufficient power.

Is it safe to plug one end into an [USB charger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbXmg.jpg), and the other one (the one carrying data) into the Raspberry Pi?  If I do this, do I risk damaging either the hard drive or the Raspberry Pi?  Normally both ends would be connected to two different ports of the same computer.

Comment: See this posting https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/32526/how-to-make-a-high-powered-usb-hard-drive-work-with-the-pi as one of the answers mentions changes to the `/boot/config.txt` to increase the amount of current available to the USB connector.

Answer (score 3):

It is generally not possible to power a HD from the Pi, which has only limited current (depending on what else is connected), due to the polyfuse.

Connecting to a USB PS will attempt to backpower the Pi. I recommend a powered hub, but even in this case some will backpower.

It is not a good idea to connect a backpowering hub at the same time as a PSU.

You can easily check whether a hub backpowers by connecting without a PSU. If the red light comes on it MAY work - depends on the "USB charger". Many do not provide a sufficiently regulated voltage.

If you want more discussion search this Forum for "backpower".

Comment: Thank you, this is all useful information (I did not know about powered hubs).  But it does not answer my question about the Y cable.  Is using this cable the same as using a powered hub?

Comment: Probably. There is no standard for Y cables (which are not in accordance with the standard). Most just have the +5V connected through. Give it a try (without the Pi PSU). You will run out of USB ports for a keyboard & mouse.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this discussion](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=29696), I thought backfeeding wasn't an issue on more recent (i.e. any Rev 1 or after boards)?

With that in mind, I don't see any problems with running the hard drive with that Y-Cable and your Pi with a separate power supply.  It'd likely be easier with a powered hub since there'd be less cables.

Answer (score -3):

Power external hard drive though USB

Comment: That will not work on an A/B pi (this question predates the +/2 models), esp. a drive that requires *two* inputs for power, as shown.